# AMCL not updating the map - odom tf when robot navigating

Tags: navigation, localization, ros

Hello Im trying to autonomously navigate a robot using ros. I have created a launch file to start the navigation stack for the robot
Here is my launch file for the robot.

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find diff_drive)/launch/cam.launch"/>

<arg name="map_file" default="$(find diff_drive)/maps/arimac_company.yaml"/>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />


<node pkg="diff_drive" type="odometry_pub.py" name="odometry"/>

<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node"
      name="robot_localization_ekf_node_odom">
  <param name="frequency" value="10." />
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.2" />
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="true" />
  <param name="publish_tf" value="true" />    
  <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom" />
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base" />
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom" />

  <param name="imu0" value="imu"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="odom"/>



  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
  

  <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/> 
  


<rosparam param="odom0_config">[true,  true,  false,
                                false, false, true,
                                true,  false, false,
                                false, false, true,
                                false, false, false]</rosparam>
                               
  <rosparam param="imu0_config">
    [false, false, false, false, false, true,
     false, false, false, false, false, true,
     true, false, false]</rosparam>

</node>



  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_mergedscan_broadcaster" args="0.114 0 0.55 0 0 0 base merged_scan 50"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_rplidar_broadcaster" args="0.114 0 0.25048 3.14 0 0 base rplidar 50"/>

<include file="$(find ira_laser_tools)/launch/laserscan_multi_merger.launch"/>


  <include file="$(find diff_drive)/launch/move_base.launch">
  </include>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
    <param name="min_particles"             value="100"/>
    <param name="max_particles"             value="5000"/>
    <param name="kld_err"                   value="0.01"/>
    <param name="update_min_d"              value="0.2"/>
    <param name="update_min_a"              value="0.2"/>
    <param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance"       value="0.1"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="0.0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="0.0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="0.0"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="50.0"/>

    <remap from="scan"                      to="scan_multi"/>
    <param name="laser_max_range"           value="30.0"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams"           value="360"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>

    <param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.1"/>

    <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>

  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_frame_id" value="base"/>
  <param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
  <param name="tf_broadcast" value="true"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

Here is my move base launch file

```
<launch>

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive)/config/global_planner_params.yaml" command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" /> 
    <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" /> 
    <rosparam file="$(find diff_drive)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <!--<remap from="odom" to="odometry/filtered"/>-->
    <param name="base_link" value="base"/>
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="/smooth_cmd_vel"/>
    <param name="move_forward_only" value="false"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

In rviz, I load the map, provide the 2D pose estimate for the robot. But when I move the robot I notice that my base positions are updating when Im moving the robot but my odom positions are not updating.

https://ibb.co/yhCzzn8

I echo the /odom topic The values are updating when Im moving the robot.

```
---
header: 
  seq: 12871
  stamp: 
    secs: 1709099520
    nsecs: 826642990
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.000436312517368
      y: 4.18431788321e-06
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0019179430571
      w: 0.999998160746
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

here is my rqt_tf_tree

https://ibb.co/Wxxy7bx

Anyone can help me to solve the issue?
Thank you